# Simplify VBA code with repetitive operations

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I created a userform with a large number of textboxes and tick boxes. When the userform is initialised, data is loaded into the textboxes and the tick box values are defined by values specified in one of the workbook tabs.

I have written code with lots of repetition. For example, I include the code below for every textbox that is populated by a number.

```vb
Controls("ll_f_m_prior").Value = Format(Range("ll_f_m_prior_p"), "standard")

If Controls("ll_f_m_prior").Value = "n/a" Or Controls("ll_f_m_prior").Value = "" Then

    Controls("ll_f_m_prior").Enabled = False

    cb1.Enabled = False

End If
```

I have 25+ textboxes where the code is repeated. I am looking for a way to call a function using two dynamic variables. In the above example, the two variables are ll_f_m_prior and cb1.

I tried this code

```vb
Sub error1(var1 As String, var2 As String)
    
Controls(var1).Value = Format(Range(var1), "standard")
    
If Controls(var1).Value = "n/a" Or Controls(var1).Value = "" Then
    
    Controls(var1).Enabled = False
    
    x = var2 & ".Enabled"
    
    x = False
    
End If
    
End Sub
```

and calling the subroutine using the function:

```
Call error1("ll_f_m_prior_p", cb1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the sub with `Call error1("ll_f_m_prior_p", cb1)` `cb1`isn't a string.
Yet the sub expects a string.
So if you change the second variable to act as an object instead, that should make things easier.

```
Sub error1(var1 As String, var2 As Object)

Controls(var1).Value = Format(Range(var1), "standard")

If Controls(var1).Value = "n/a" Or Controls(var1).Value = "" Then
   Controls(var1).Enabled = False
   var2.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Christofer, thanks for your help. I made the changes above and I'm getting an error. So, currently, the call routine is within a large sub routine. I've placed the above code in a separate module1 and when I start the userform I'm getting the following error message: "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined"

Comment: Sounds like it can't find the sub. Try making it a `Public Sub` instead, and see if that helps.